# How to change default browser for wine steam game?

Tags: wine, steam, browser

I want to play windows steam game (duel link) on linux.

Game is working fine, but when I login with my game account. 
Its open linux browser (firefox).
I login in in firefox then it say "login process, this window will automatically close when its done"
Im waiting more than 10m, but firefox still not closing.
And game waiting login success from browser.

I rasisme its because linux browser cant work well with wine.
Im install firefox in my wine too. But the game still opening linux browser.

What i ask.
How to set wine browser (firefox) as my default browser game wine?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried just downloading steam through synaptic/ whatever default software installer is on your computer? Steam is supported in linux, so you can log in through the client without the need for WINE and a browser.

If you do need wine to run the game, I suggest downloading winetricks though the terminal with these commands:

```
wget  https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Winetricks/winetricks/master/src/winetricks
chmod +x winetricks
```

then run it. click ok. select install a windows dll. choose a web browser to download.

Comment: But i want play windows game, so i need wine steak.

Comment: @Nyamuk Most games downloaded from steam run on Linux without WINE! It's pretty cool isn't it?

Comment: Sure its cool, but i want play specific game that only run in Windows. (Duel link)

Comment: @Nyamuk Which game is it? I will look into it. That being said, it won't hurt to try..... If anything just open steam in wine and download the game through there. Then click play in the steam client. It won't open a browser and your problem should be fixed.

Comment: @Nyamuk i updated my answer :)

Answer (score 0):

If you use `Q4wine`, there is a `Wine Browsers` setting tab for default browser in Q4Wine `Setup > System > Update Fake Drive` setting dialog. I think it does sth. similar as below, but a lot better.

This may or may not work for steam game, but worked for my work application:

1. Follow this to set the class handlers right.
   http://www.webupd8.org/2010/03/how-to-make-wine-open-links-in-your.html
   in short :

   - In regedit find `HKCU> Software> Wine> WineBrowser` set `Browsers` to `xdg-open,firefox,konqueror,mozilla,netscape,galeon,opera,dillo`
   - Find `HKCR> https/http/htmlfile> shell> open`,  set `command` to: `C:\windows\system32\winebrowser.exe -nohome "%1"`
   - Now it should work, but not in my case...
2. My app is a 64-bit exe, this simply doesn't work after the setup, need some fiddling, try:

   > WINEDEBUG=warn+all wine myworkapp

   After trigged the launch action in the work app, in the console you should see debug info about what is missing. In my case:

   > 01a4:warn:ntdll:NtQueryAttributesFile L"\??\C:\windows\system32\winebrowser.exe" not found (c0000034)

   which is weird, since there exists `~/.wine/drive_c/windows/system32/winebrowser.exe`

   > wine cmd
   >
   > echo 1 > c:\windows\system32\mark1

   mark1 is in `~/.wine/drive_c/windows/syswow64`, so just a symbolink will fix it.

   > cd ~/.wine/drive_c/windows/syswow64
   >   ln -sf ../system32/winebrowser.exe winebrowser.exe

Now it works, though the workapp still complain default browser not found, the long link opens fine in linux browser.